# Excess qty adding into cart when adding product in cart with custom option programmatically

Tags: magento2, product, cart, addtocart, controllers

I am using this the following code to add a product in cart with custom option value. But all the time cart qty taking the value of  "Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart" and then adding 1. For example if the  Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart value is 10, then qty in cart taken 11 and the giving the warning "The requested qty exceeds the maximum qty allowed in shopping cart". I am using the following code.

```
$gproductId = 16213;
            $product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($gproductId);
            $cart = $objectManager->create('Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');  
            $formKey = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey')->getFormKey();  
            $option = array('49064'=>'865759');

            $params = array(
            'form_key' => $formKey,
            'product' => $gproductId, //product Id
            'item' => $gproductId, //product Id
            'qty'   =>0, //quantity of product                
            'options' => $option,
            'allow_partial_payment' => 0
            );

            // echo "<pre>"; print_r($params); die();                   
             try {                  
             $cart->addProduct($gproductId, $params);
             $cart->save();
            }  catch (\Exception $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();

            }
```

Please let me know if you have any solution for this problem.